# Formula Error when trying to compute from void function

Tags: c++, formula, trigonometry, calculus

Can anyone help tell me what I did in my "void sinx" funcction?  I should get an answer of 27.7714 but instead it is returning 0.  Here is the formula I am trying to compute.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wi70z.png)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

void sinx(int n, int x, int k, int num, double &fraction, double &final);

int main()
{
int x, n, k, m, i, num, fact;
double fraction, final; 

cout<<"Enter your values for x and n: ";
cin>>x>>n;

sinx(n, x, k, num, fraction, final);

cout<<"Your final value is for sin(x) is:"<<final;

}

void sinx(int n, int x, int k, int num, double &fraction, double &final)
{
k=2*n+1;
int m = k, fact = 1, i;
for(i=1; i<=m; i++)
fact = fact * i;

num=pow(-1,n);
fraction=num/fact;
x=pow(x,k);

final=fraction*x;
}
```

Here is my output:

Enter your values for x and n: 6
4
Your final value is for sin(x) is:0

Any help wold be greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of your variables are not inialized, so I don't know what their value is on your system. Your compiler should have warned you about this.

Besides this, you are dividing by `fact` which i assume is factorial, so probably a big number. Because this division is happening with two ints, it will become zero. You should probably cast both to `double` before you divide.

A tip for situations like this: get a debugger running, and step through your program. That way you will see what the values are, and you will understand what happens.

Comment: Man, you were right on point.  when taking my factorial, it required double. as well as did my input for x so I could accept decimals.  Thanks!  Problem solved!